# How to create a .bat file that starts a customized CMD, in which it run a script?

Tags: batch-file, automation, build-automation, cmd

I want to make a automated program in .bat. The program needs to run a command. However, the command must be run from a custom CMD.

If I open a regular CMD, the commands that I will do:

1. C:\Hardware\bin\StartCustomCMD.bat init (This is the first thing I will type. It starts the custom CMD.)
2. bb autobuild (This is the second thing that I will type. The command goes into the custom CMD)

You can probably tell that I did not write these scripts. I am trying to set this up in Windows Scheduler so that the script gets run automatically every day. Any help on how can I do that?

Thanks.

Comment: Why not copy StartCustomCMD.bat, add your line, save it and schedule the newly created script...?

Comment: I guess that works too. But it will soon get ugly when I try to add other stuff into the script...

Answer (score 0):

Make yourself a new batch file, and embed the other things into it, and then run that.

```
@echo off
call C:\Hardware\bin\StartCustomCMD.bat
bb autobuild
```

If `bb` it itself a batch file, then use `call` on it also. What `call` does is execute another batch file, and then continue processing. If you don't use `call`, when you run one batch file from another, the latter 'takes over' and the caller does not continue.

Answer (score 0):

To do this you can use the timeout and goto command. Timeout waits a period of time in seconds but it can be skipped by pressing any key while cmd is open at the top layer. If you can see cmd press its icon on the desktop until you can not see it. Then using the goto command you can go to the top line. So here would be your script:

```
:start
C:\Hardware\bin\StartCustomCMD.bat init  
bb autobuild  
timeout 86400
goto start
```

You already know what the first two commands do, but `timeout 86400` waits exactly one day then the `goto start` command goes to the first command so that gets repeated. If you need to add any more commands then put them above the `timeout 86400` command.